# Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists open set $G_\varepsilon \subset \Bbb R^n$. Show that $A$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists open set $G_\varepsilon \subset \Bbb R^n$ for which $A \subset G_\varepsilon$ and $m^*(G_\varepsilon \setminus A) < \varepsilon$. Show that $A$ is measurable.

$A$ is Lebesgue measurable if it satisfies the Caratheodory's criterion that is for arbitary $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ the equality $$m^*(E)=m^*(E \cap A) + m^*(E \setminus A)$$ holds.

Now for $G_\varepsilon$ I have that $$m^*(G_\varepsilon)=m^*(G_\varepsilon \cap A)+ m^*(G_\varepsilon \setminus A) \le m^*(G_\varepsilon \cap A) + \varepsilon$$

but since $A \subset G_\varepsilon$, then $G_\varepsilon \cap A= A$ and so $$m^*(G_\varepsilon) \le m^*(A) + \varepsilon$$

but how does this imply that $A$ would be measurable?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1353503/42969

Answer (score 1):

For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, choose an open set $U_{k}$ such that
$A\subseteq U_{k}$ and $m^{\ast}(U_{k}\setminus A)<\frac{1}{k}$.
Let $G=\cap_{k}U_{k}$, which is a Borel set. Clearly $A\subseteq G$.
By monotonicity of outer-measure, $m^{\ast}(G\setminus A)\leq m^{\ast}(U_{k}\setminus A)<\frac{1}{k}$
for each $k$. Since $k$ is arbitrary, we have that $m^{\ast}(G\setminus A)=0$. Recall that sets having zero outer-measure are Lebesgue measurable.
Therefore $G\setminus A$ is Lebesgue measurable. Finally, $A=G\backslash(G\setminus A)$, which is Lebesgue
measurable.